# How to create a random number between a range with a set number of duplicates in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have an access DB with a table called "Lab_Samples" which has the following fields

Lab_Sample_ID - a unique value
Batch_No - A batch of work that the sample belongs to.
Box_No - A box No number that the sample should go to between 1 and 10

There are 60 samples per batch and I want to randomly assign the Lab_Sample_ID to a box_no between 1 and 10. Each box has to have exactly 6 samples so the random number has to repeat exactly 6 times

how would I do this in SQL/Access?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you really have to do this in MS Access?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  unfortunately Yes.  I could probably achieve this in R or Python with much greater ease.  If there are ways to get VBA to run an R or python scirpt within access I would be open to trialing that.  Alternatively, I was thinking I could make numbers 1-60 and for numbers greater than 10 to subtract 10 off.  This latter solution wouldn't be ideal but would achieve what I needed in a short term.  But not quite sure on that either.

Comment: . . Sad.  Using R with MS Access is like attaching training wheels on a sports car.  This would be much simpler in almost any other database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function *QrnInteger* from my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).

The in-line comments show typical usage:

```vb
' Retrieves one random integer value between a minimum and a maximum value.
' By default, a value of 0 or 1 will be returned.
'
' The minimum and maximum values can be preset by calling the functions:
'
'   QrnIntegerMaximum NewMaximumValue
'   QrnIntegerMinimum NewMinimumValue
'
' Acceptable minimum/maximum values are about +/-10E+16.
'
' Example:
'   QrnIntegerMinimum 10
'   QrnIntegerMaximum 20
'   RandomInteger = QrnInteger
'   RandomInteger -> 14
'
' Values will be retrieved from the source in batches to
' relief the burden on the API service and to speed up
' the time to retrieve single values.
'
' The default size of a batch is preset by the constant
' DefaultSize in function QrnIntegerSize.
' The size of the batch (cache) can be preset by calling the function:
'
'   QrnIntegerSize NewCacheSize
'
' Argument Id is for use in a query to force a call of QrnInteger
' for each record to retrieve a random id:
'
'   Select *, QrnInteger([SomeField]) As RandomId
'   From SomeTable
'
' Minimum and/or maximum values of the retrieved ids can be set
' from the query itself, for example 1 and 100 respectively:
'
'   Select *, QrnInteger([SomeField]) As RandomId
'   From SomeTable
'   Where QrnIntegerMinimum(1) > 0 And QrnIntegerMaximum(100) > 0
'
' 2019-12-26. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function QrnInteger( _
    Optional Id As Variant) _
    As Variant

    Static Values           As Variant
    Static LastIndex        As Long
    Static CurrentMaximum   As Variant
    Static CurrentMinimum   As Variant
    
    Dim Value               As Variant
    
    If CurrentMaximum <> QrnIntegerMaximum Or CurrentMinimum <> QrnIntegerMinimum Then
        ' Reset cache.
        CurrentMaximum = QrnIntegerMaximum
        CurrentMinimum = QrnIntegerMinimum
        LastIndex = 0
    End If
    
    If LastIndex = 0 Then
        ' First run, a reset, or all values have been retrieved.
        ' (Re)set LastIndex to the size of the cache.
        LastIndex = QrnIntegerSize
        ' Retrieve a new set of values.
        Values = QrnIntegers(LastIndex, CurrentMinimum, CurrentMaximum)
    End If
    
    ' Get the next value.
    ' The index of the array is zero-based.
    LastIndex = LastIndex - 1
    Value = Values(LastIndex)
    
    QrnInteger = Value

End Function
```

For your case, you could set the cache:

```
QrnIntegerSize 60
```